# Where can I download WSO2 App Factory

Tags: wso2

WSO2 folks,

I would like to take a look and try out WSO2 App Factory, but I didn't find the download link on wso2.com or wso2.org. I also tried the "WSO2 App Factory in Action Try Online" link, but it gave me 404 page. Is App Factory a product that is supposed to be downloadable by customers, or it's just a service provide on the cloud? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 App Factory is not released yet and you will be able to download once it is ready.

It's supposed to be downloaded by users and set up in their own environment.

You can find more information from following links:
http://wso2.com/cloud/app-factory/
http://blog.cobia.net/cobiacomm/2012/04/16/what-is-wso2-appfactory/
http://blog.samisa.org/2013/06/agile-development-with-cloud-computing.html

"Try Online" link should work. I'm not sure why it gave you a 404 page.

Please access the preview from following link.

https://appfactorypreview.wso2.com

I hope this helps.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your reply Isuru! And I tried https://appfactorypreview.wso2.com/ but it gave me a 404 again when I try to sign up, and did nothing after I input my email and password.

Comment: And BTW, when is App Factory going to release?

Comment: WSO2 App Factory is planned to release in next month. Please subscribe to WSO2 mailing lists. You will be able to find out more information there. http://wso2.com/mail

Answer (score 0):

App Factory has actually been released both as an online service and for download.

Online platform as a service: http://wso2.com/cloud/app-cloud/

Download for your own deployments: http://wso2.com/cloud/app-factory/